# Visual Studio 2015- XamlParseException was unhandled

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to add a new tab to the main window in my Windows Forms Application, but I'm currently getting an exception when I try to run the application, which says `XamlParseException was unhandled`. The exception gives the description:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'RiviamAgent.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

The `XML` for the application is:

```
<Window x:Class="RiviamAgent.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="RIVIAM | CONNECTOR" Height="640" Width="640"
    ResizeMode="NoResize">

<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Application" >
            <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Background="White">
                <MenuItem Header="_View">
                    <MenuItem Header="_Connections">
                        <MenuItem x:Name="rivMenu" Header="_RIVIAM Cloud" Click="connectorInfo">
                        </MenuItem>
                        <Separator />
                        <MenuItem x:Name="tppMenu" Header="_TPP SystmOne" Click="connectorInfo">
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem x:Name="emisMenu" Header="_EMIS Web" Click="connectorInfo">
                        </MenuItem>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Diagnostics" Click="diagMode"/>

                    <MenuItem Header="_About" Click="About_Riviam"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Height="100" Width="100">
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="Riviam">
                        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="Browser">
                        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" />
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>
            </Menu>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Browser"></TabItem>
    </TabControl>


    <Image x:Name="rivlogo" Height="128" Width="128" Margin="451,49,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="ic_launcher.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="connectedFlag" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="479,193,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="cloud.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="disconnectedFlag" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="479,193,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="cloud_dark.png"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="unsentMsgs" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="479,193,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Text="!"/>

    <Image x:Name="tppFlag" Source="tppswoosh.png"  Margin="529,193,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width ="60"/>
    <Image x:Name="emisFlag" Source="emiswoosh.png"  Margin="529,193,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width ="60"/>


    <TextBlock x:Name="blah1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,52,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select service to refer to:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="blah2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,89,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="56" Width="136"><Run Text="Select referral document:
                                                                                                                                                           (or drag it to the logo)"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="blahfoot" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="319,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="RIVIAM - Secure cloud for Health and Social Care" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="24" Width="260"/>

    <ComboBox x:Name="serviceList" Text="pls select"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="182,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218" ></ComboBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="fileName" Text=" " MaxLines="1" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="182,90,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="23" Width="161"/>
    <Button x:Name="fileBtn" Content="Browse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52" Click="fileUpload" Height="23"/>
    <Button x:Name="referBtn" Content="Send Referral and Patient Record" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="182,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218" Click="referThis" Height="23"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="blahfoot_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,198,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="49" Width="361"><Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Notice"/><Run Text=": "/><Run Text="You must ensure that the patient has agreed to their data being shared "/><Run Text="with the provider. Please contact the RIVIAM help desk on 01225 945 020 if you are unsure."/></TextBlock>

    <!-- end of normal view -->

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroller" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="39,329,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="244" Width="327">
        <TextBox x:Name="infoPane" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="nothing" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    
    <Button x:Name="f1Btn" Content="view Logs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="408,361,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" Click="testFunction1"/>
    <Button x:Name="f2Btn" Content="delete logs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="408,393,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" Click="testFunction2"/>
    <Button x:Name="f3Btn" Content="test function 3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="408,425,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" Click="testFunction3"/>

    <Button x:Name="cntxtBtn" Content="context" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="408,553,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" Click="Context_Click"/>

    
            


</Grid>
</Window>
```

The only edit I've made to this `XML` since it was last working is to add the tags:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Application" >
        ...
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Browser"></TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

In the 'preview' panel in Visual Studio, where the XML written in the XAML file is displayed, I can see that the changes I have made are displayed correctly, i.e. the window is showing two tabs- 'Application' & 'Browser', but for some reason, I'm getting the `XamlParseException` when I try to run the application.

Most of the related questions I found on SO seem to suggest that I need to add a `try-catch` block to my constructor in my C#- I've tried this, but it doesn't make a difference, and given that the only thing I've changed since my application was last working is the `.xaml` file, I would have thought that the issue is something to do with the XML- anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit**

Having clicked 'View Detail' in the exception window, it seems that the line it's complaining about is the declaration of my `Browser.cs` class:

```
partial class Browser{
```

The error says:

> The invocation of the constructor on type 'Agent.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'."}

which is the `partial class Browser{` line quoted above...

**Edit**

Having looked into it a bit further, it seems that the exception is being thrown when `MainWindow` is called... The only call to `MainWindow` in the entire solution is the first line of the XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="Agent.MainWindow"
    ... >
```

How would I handle an XML exception such as this?

Comment: To debug such things - indeed add try-catch to your window constructor (around InitializeComponent() call) and _inspect inner exception in debugger_.

Comment: How do I inspect inner exception in debugger? That's not something I've used before... When I try to run the code, and it breaks, I get the exception message that I quoted in my OP... If I click on 'View Detail', it shows the message: `The invocation of the constructor on type 'RiviamAgent.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'."}`, but I don't see any options to inspect the inner exception...?

Comment: Well InnerException is one of the properties of Exception class, so you just inspect it as any other property in debugger.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can do that... When I run the program, it throws the exception almost straight away (before the application is launched). In the Error list, I get a line that says `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`... not sure what that means/ whether that's something I need to look into? The Error list says: 0 Errors, 14 Warnings, 2 Messages

Comment: try {
      InitializeComponent();
}
catch (XamlParseException ex) {
     var inner = ex.InnerException;
     Debug.WriteLine(inner);
}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- I gave that a go, but still get the same `XamlParseException was unhandled` message when running my code...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110976/discussion-between-evk-and-someone2088).

Comment: Having 'viewed the detail' or the error, I've edited my question to show the line that the underlying error is complaining about...